# Heroku: how does "log-runtime-metrics" collect statistics,under the hood?

Tags: heroku

I'm looking into Heroku performance monitoring.
In particular I found "log-runtime-metrics", and was wondering how it collects statistics under the hood? Is there some heroku API that exposes the state of each dyno (memory, cpu etc)? Or is it some Amazon API? Linux API?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've recently asked the same question to Heroku directly.

Check out http://log2viz.herokuapp.com/

You should see your App(s) available in in a list and can view real-time metrics there. This link isn't documented from the lab page https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/log-runtime-metrics